# jQuery addClass() with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to develop my php platform.

When i try to use this javascript snippet

```
if(result == "OK"){
    // If the result is OK applies some effects
    $("#signup" + item).removeClass("error");
    $("#signup" + item).addClass("success");
} else {
    // Applies some effects and shows the error
    $("#signup" + item).removeClass("success");
    $("#signup" + item).addClass("error");
}
```

with this html code

```
<input class="xlarge" id="signupUsername" name="signupUsername" size="30" type="text">
```

Nothing happens. The "error" or "success" effects are not applied.

Comment: Are you sure the code is executed? Did you include the right CSS? Did you define the "error" and "success" CSS classes? Does "item" contain the right value? ...

Comment: The css is correctly included because the page is correctly styled. Error and success classes are defined in the Bootstrap .less files that are correctly compiled by less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`error` and `success` classes shouldn't be applied to `<input>`, but to containing `<div>` with class `clearfix`:

```
<div class="clearfix error">
    <input id="errorInput" class="xlarge" type="text" size="30" name="errorInput"/>
</div>

<div class="clearfix success">
    <input id="successInput" class="xlarge" type="text" size="30" name="successInput"/>
</div>
```

Try changing your code to add/remove classes to parent `div.clearfix` and see if it works then.

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <input class="xlarge" id="signupUsername" name="signupUsername" size="30" type="text">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var div = $("#signup" + item).parent("div.clearfix");
if(result == "OK"){
    div.removeClass("error");
    div.addClass("success");
} else {
    div.removeClass("success");
    div.addClass("error");
}
```